# Uncatchable flaw in file reading

Tags: c

Can anyone tell me the flaw in this program...? Actually it is printing the last record twice.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int accountNum;
  char name[30];
  double balance;
  int counter = 0;

  FILE *clientDataFile1;

  if( (clientDataFile1 = fopen("clients.txt", "r")) == NULL )
    printf("File could not be opened");
  else
  {
    printf("%-10s %-13s %s\n", "Account", "Name", "Balance");

    while( !feof(clientDataFile1) )
    {
      fscanf(clientDataFile1, "%d%s%lf", &accountNum, name, &balance);      
      printf( "%-10d%-13s%.2lf\n", accountNum, name, balance );
    }

    printf("\n\n\n");
    rewind(clientDataFile1);    
    counter++;
    fclose(clientDataFile1);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

This is getting really painful.I tried many times but the flaw was uncatchable. Either the working is not clear to me or Ubuntu 12.10 or gcc is responsible for this.
Help me....

Comment: Why are you rewinding just to close it? Files are not VHS tapes.

Comment: Minor: Suggest `"%d%29s%lf"` to prevent `name` overflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using `feof()` in a manner which seems very popular by beginners, but unfortunately is still wrong.

The point of `feof()` is to query, *after* an I/O error has occurred, if it occured because end of file had been reached. It should *not* be used to prematurely decide if the file has ended.

Just do the read until it fails.

```
while( fscanf(clientDataFile1, "%d%s%lf", &accountNum, name, &balance) == 3 )
{
    printf( "%-10d%-13s%.2lf\n", accountNum, name, balance );
}
```

Comment: so what should I do know to check whether or not the end of file is reached.

Comment: @Maddy You do see my code, right? The `fscanf()` will fail when the end of file is reached, you don't need to look for that particular failure.

Comment: your solution is restricted to known values. what if we have to check them on dynamic files and records...

Comment: @Maddy Please post a new question, it sounds as if you have more things you want help with. :)

Answer (score 4):

After reading the answer from @unwind, I got curious as to what `feof()` does, and why this causes the double-print of the last record.

From [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/feof/): "Notice that stream's internal position indicator may point to the end-of-file for the next operation, but still, the end-of-file indicator may not be set until an operation attempts to read at that point."

So you're reaching EOF, and printing the last record, but the flag that `feof()` checks hasn't been set yet. Then, on the next iteration of the loop you do a `fscanf` which fails due to being past EOF. This failure causes the flag to be set, making this the last iteration of the loop. This iteration still prints what is already saved in the `accountnum`, `name`, and `balance` variables, thus you see the last record twice.

Comment: It can work either way.  Imagine a text file where the last line may or may not have a newline.  You won't know until you read the last line whether there is anything on it.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: your while loop should look like this :

```
while (!feof(clientDataFile1))
{
  if (EOF == fscanf(clientDataFile1, "%d%s%lf", &accountNum, name, &balance))
    break ;

  printf( "%-10d%-13s%.2lf\n", accountNum, name, balance );
}
```

Comment: `while(1) { if (EOF == fscanf(...) break; ...}` would do the same thing.  No need for `feof()`.

Comment: @chux: correct, but I left if left `feof` "just to be sure".

Answer (score 0):

**while( fscanf(clientDataFile, "%d%s%lf", &accountNum, name, &balance) *!= EOF* )
            printf( "%-10d%-13s%.2lf\n", accountNum, name, balance);**

Actually value of EOF is -1 and fscanf() returns the number of inputed variables. So, expression != evaluates 0 when value of fscanf() is equal to EOF which is -1 and hence the break in while is achieved.